# creating DAT file in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I tried to create dat file using Oracle SQL.Dat file is created but below query output is not writing in Data File.Dat file created with 0kb size.

```
set echo off
set feedback off
set linesize 100
set pagesize 0
set head off
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
spool on
spool D:\Dat\empfeed.dat
select EMPNO||','||ENAME||','||SAL||','||NVL(COMM,0)||','||JOB||','||DEPTNO||','||HIREDATE
FROM EMP;
spool off
exit
```